# Hacer doble split en Java y obtener dos conjuntos de valores

Tags: java, array

Estoy recibiendo esta cadena en Java:

```
Respuesta1_10|Respuesta2_50|Respuesta4_90|Respuesta5_33
```

Y necesito construir con ella dos grupos de valores de forma dinámica, ya que la cantidad de valores separados por `|` no es fija. Los grupos de valores serían:

- respuestas
- estatus

Para leerlos no hay problemas, lo hago así:

```
    String str="Respuesta1_10|Respuesta2_50|Respuesta4_90|Respuesta5_33";
    String[] splitUno =str.split("\\|");

    for (int x=0; x<splitUno.length; x++) 
    {
        String splitDos[]=splitUno[x].split("\\_");
        System.out.println(splitDos[0]);
        System.out.println(splitDos[1]+"\n");
    }
}
```

En la salida tengo:

```
Respuesta1
10

Respuesta2
50

Respuesta4
90

Respuesta5
33
```

Pero quisiera saber si hay alguna forma más fácil de crear dos conjuntos de valores sin tener que pasar por el bucle `for`.

Es decir, pasar esto:

```
Respuesta1_10|Respuesta2_50|Respuesta4_90|Respuesta5_33
```

A algo así más o menos:

```
String[] arrRespuestas = {"Respuesta1", "Respuesta2", "Respuesta3", "Respuesta5"};
int[] arrEstatus = {10, 50, 90, 33};
```

Comment: No se me ocurre una forma de evitar el bucle. Pero si hubiese algún método nativo, internamente estaría iterando al igual que en tu código... Una alternativa es no hacer el split, sino capturar lo que coincide con un regex. Si te interesa, sería algo como http://rextester.com/TDNX10321 (pero no evita el bucle).

Answer (score 2):

La entrada de Split es una Regex (Expresión regular), de modo que si pones como entrada una expresión regular que cumpla ambos separadores.

un ejemplo sería:

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    String aux = "Resultado1_10|Resultado2_20";
    String[] spliteado = aux.split("[|]|_");
    for(String a:spliteado)
        System.out.println(a);
 }
}
```

[Prueba online el código](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php)

[Información de Split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

[Para probar Regex online](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Gracias. Había contemplado la posibilidad de hacer el split usando los dos separadores en un regex, pero no veo la forma de almacenar en variables cada grupo de valores.