# ¿Como anidar splits en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

A raíz de [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/100505/hacer-doble-split-en-java-y-obtener-dos-conjuntos-de-valores), me puse a pensar, que se trata de un patrón bastante habitual, interpretar una cadena con "parejas" de valores separados por algún caracter, y ¿como resolverlo en Python?. Veamos el ejemplo:

Tenemos esta cadena:

```
texto = "Respuesta1_10|Respuesta2_50|Respuesta4_90|Respuesta5_33"
```

y deseamos transformarla en dos variables tipo lista de la siguiente forma:

```
respuestas = ["Respuesta1", "Respuesta2", "Respuesta3", "Respuesta5"]
status = [10, 50, 90, 33]
```

¿Que formas tenemos en Python para lograrlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como pides *"modos"* de resolverlo, uno de los más apropiados sería usando *expresiones regulares*, muy similar a la respuesta de java que indicas.

Suponiendo que la cadena de texto tenga el formato sugerido, podemos usar una expresión regular para cortarla tanto por el carácter `'_'` como por `'|'` y hacer algo así:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile("_|[|]")

texto = "Respuesta1_10|Respuesta2_50|Respuesta4_90|Respuesta5_33" 
words = pattern.split(texto)
```

Ahora `words` es una lista con el siguiente contenido:

```
['Respuesta1',
 '10',
 'Respuesta2',
 '50',
 'Respuesta4',
 '90',
 'Respuesta5',
 '33']
```

Para separar las dos listas basta con *rebanar* `words`:

```
respuestas = words[::2]
status = words[1::2]
```

También se puede crear algo mixto entre *expresiones regulares* y *unzip*. Es más compleja, pero usa iteradores, con lo que es más eficiente en caso de procesar cadenas de texto muy largas:

```
import re

pat = re.compile('([^|]+)_([^|]+)')

texto = "Respuesta1_10|Respuesta2_50|Respuesta4_90|Respuesta5_33"

respuestas, status = zip(*(m.groups() for m in pat.finditer(texto)))
```

Comment: Estupendo, lo del "slice" por pares e impares, muy buenas opciones.

Answer (score 1):

La forma que creo es la más compacta, no sé si la más óptima es la siguiente:

```
texto = "Respuesta1_10|Respuesta2_50|Respuesta4_90|Respuesta5_33"

Respuesta,Status = zip(*[e.split("_") for e in str.split("|")])

print(Respuesta)
print(Status)
```

Básicamente mediante comprensión de listas armamos el primer [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) separando cada pareja de valores mediante el pipe `|` y retornamos a su vez un nuevo [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split), esta vez por el guión bajo `_`, los cual nos armaría una lista como está:

```
[['Respuesta1', '10'], ['Respuesta2', '50'], ['Respuesta4', '90'], ['Respuesta5', '33']]
```

Por último, hacemos un `unzip` mediante [`zip(*[lista])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) y conseguimos nuestras dos variables con las tuplas correspondientes:

```
('Respuesta1', 'Respuesta2', 'Respuesta4', 'Respuesta5')
('10', '50', '90', '33')
```